# android json unicode parsing issue

Tags: android, json, unicode

I'm using `Volley library` in my project to get a json file from server. then i parse the file to get different strings which are in Unicode format. for example:

```
String text=jsnObject.getString("name");
```

and the value of name in my json file is:

```
\u00D8\u00B3\u00D9\u2026\u00D8\u00B3\u00D8\u00A7\u00D8\u00B1\u00DB\u0152
```

but when i log the value of text string, it shows me the below value:

```
Ø³Ù…Ø³Ø§Ø±ÛŒ
```

why doesn't it show me the correct value which is actually a word in arabic?!

Answer (score 1):

to get different language use **utf8_encode(string)** at php side.